# Django forms request.user

Tags: django, django-forms

I my model users can create rifles and this rifle is obviously associated with a User.

```
class Gun(ImageModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    ...  
    ...  
    ...
```

I have another model which is dependent on this and need to make use of the users rifles, but when the user adds a record I only want to display his rifles.

mt model looks as follows

```
class Trophies(ImageModel):  
    used_his = models.ForeignKey(Gun)
```

my form looks as follows

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from models import Trophies
from gunsafe.models import Gun
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TrophiesForm(request.user, ModelForm):
    used_his = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gun.objects.filter(user__id=1))

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrophiesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['used_his'].queryset = User.objects.filter(pk = user)
```

I was wondering how I can get the current logged in users ID instead of the `user__id=1`

Here is the view.

```
def edit(request, trophy_id, template_name='trophies/edit.html'):
    trophy = Trophies.objects.get(pk=trophy_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TrophiesForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=trophy)
        if form.is_valid():
            newform = form.save(commit=False)
            newform.user = request.user
            newform.save()  
            ...  
            ...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by overriding the `__init__()` method of the form, passing in an instance of `User` and filtering the `queryset` using that user. Something like this:

```
class TrophiesForm(ModelForm):
    used_his = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gun.objects.filter(user__id=1))

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrophiesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['used_his'].queryset = User.objects.filter(pk = user.id)
```

In your view you can pass in the appropriate (currently logged in) instance of `User`.

```
def my_trophies(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    form = TrophiesForm(user)
    ...
```

Comment: I amended some code and pasted the view in there.

Based on this I still get an error. __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given), maybe you can point out where I am going wrong with this. much appreciated

Comment: @ApPel: can you pass the user instance as the _first_ argument to the form's constructor and try again? `form = TrophiesForm(request.user, ...)`.

Comment: basedon the changes when I add request.user as the first argument I just get 'name "request" is not defined'

Comment: @Manoj: Pasted the updated version for you. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: @ApPel: This line from your model is wrong. `self.fields['used_his'].queryset = User.objects.filter(pk = user)`. The filter should be `pk = user.id`.

Comment: @ApPel: This line in the view needs to change: `form = TrophiesForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=trophy)`. Change to `form = TrophiesForm(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES, instance=trophy)`

Answer (score 10):

Another angle to Manoj's submission ...

use a kwarg to pass user data, as to not mess with the method signature since it expects request.POST as the first argument. A better convention would be as follows.

```
class TrophiesForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #using kwargs
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(TrophiesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['used_his'].queryset = User.objects.filter(pk = user.id)
```

Now in the call, this is more explicit and follows a better signature convention

```
form = TrophiesForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
```

You could also use instance: (note the super before you grab the instance obj)

```
class TrophiesForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubmissionUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.instance.user
        self.fields['used_his'].queryset = User.objects.filter(pk = user.id)
```

You can then call in your views.py like so:

```
form = TrophiesForm(instance=*MyModel*(user=request.user))
```