# Get request in form field validation

Tags: django, forms, validation, request, field

I have a form, where validation depends on logged user. For some users are certain values valid, for other users they are invalid. What is valid and what is invalid is dynamic - I can't create new form for each user group.

What's more I need this same validation in more forms, so I created custom form field. To this custom form field I need to pass user instance somehow to check if the value is valid or not.

How to do this?

Answer (score 10):

I am doing it like that:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    # doing stuff with the user…
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your view class/method you have to instantiate the form like this:

```
form = EventForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extra field for this.

You can access the current user by [passing it explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1204136/630877) or by [fetching it from the request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533325/630877) in your form's `init()` method.

Then you can use the retrieved value when [cleaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) your form.

If you need this functionality in several forms I'd create either a [base class](https://github.com/pydanny/advanced-django-forms-usage#try-it-with-inheritance) that the specialized forms inherit from or create a mixin that adds the desired functionality.