# Django - can I get the current user when I'm not in a view function

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, model

I have Company and CompanyUser models. CompanyUser has 1:1 relationship with the django's auth User model. Every user is part of some company, so I have a ForeignKey field (Company) in the CompanyUser model:

```
class CompanyUser(models.Model):
    Company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    User = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Now I want to create some html tables to view and filter the data about Sales, Products, etc. I'm using django-tables2 and that works great.

Now let's say I want to see the Sales of a particular Product. So I need a dropdown that contains all Products of the Company that the user belongs to.

I've have created the forms.py file in my app:

```
from django import forms

class SaleFilterForm(forms.Form):
    product_id = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(Company=???))
    ...
    ...
```

So my question is. How to get the current user, when I'm inside forms.py file? I don't have the "request" object there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views.py

```
def yourview(request):
    yourform = SaleFilterForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Forms.py

```
class SaleFilterForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(SaleFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can use your user inside of your form as `self.user`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think I can.. I'm getting "name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: Hi, check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202839/get-request-data-in-django-form .. maybe you are missing something :)

Comment: Damn, this is quite challenging. The problem is this line: "product_id=forms.ChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(Company=???))" ... I'm not inside the method so yeah.. there's no self.. I'm stuck..

Comment: You can define your fields or use your queryset inside of your init... There is no problem at all..example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3533325/3350765

Comment: sorry for bothering you, but I can't make this to work.. see my form here: http://pastebin.com/DaKCvAM1   it outputs nothing :(

Comment: I think it's because you are using the super, you have also to define wich field will be in your form out of init, like the example that I sent.

Comment: With that example I'm getting: 'SaleFilterForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: or if I use "self.product_id.queryset" i get: 'SaleFilterForm' object has no attribute 'product_id'... but it totally does.. you can see in my form

Comment: I created a chat room, go there

Answer (score -1):

This is the best simple code in Django to pass user information form views.py to various files is by using a function

in the file, you want to access the current user info (ex:models.py) :
after all imports

`

```
user = None
def current_user(request):
    global user
    user = request.user
```

`

and use the object variable **user** in the file

**in views.py:**

`from .models import current_user`

in any function(eg-def login(request):)

`current_user(request)`

It is just based on simple sending variable via the function. Simple logic

Comment: Sorry Dan R it's an typo.