# Django How I can pass request.user(current logged user) in forms when I use class based view?

Tags: python, django

I wanted to pass request.user to show current user in a form with ModelMultipleChoiceField. I could figure out my problem thanks to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184373/6568309. I fixed my code like below.

**but I could get solution with only function based view.** well, I kept using class based views because I could use generic views and it was recommended in first place. **Is it way to pass request.user like below with class based view(to use FormView or ModelFormView)? Additionally, Is is normal to mix function based views and class based views to meet your need in Django?**

thank you in advance.

forms.py

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(initial='testname',max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    position = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    uperall = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['uperall'].queryset = User.objects.filter(username=user.username)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', UserList.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^create/$', UserCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^test/$', TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
    url(r'^test1/$', views.ftestview, name='test1'),
]
```

views.py

```
def ftestview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

    form = CustomForm(request.POST, user=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        position = form.cleaned_data['position']

        with transaction.atomic():
            user = User.objects.create(username=username,email=email)
            userinfo = UserInfo.objects.create(user=user,phone=phone_number,position=position)
            userinfo.save()
            user.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')

else:
    form = CustomForm(user=request.user)

return render(request, 'manager/alltoall.html', { 'form': form })
```

according to answer from levi thanksfully. I changed my code like below

views.py

```
class TestView(FormView):
    form_class = CustomForm
    template_name = 'manager/alltoall.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        user = self.request.user
        form_kwargs = super(TestView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs.update({'initial': {'uperall': User.objects.filter(username=user.username)}})
        return form_kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        position = form.cleaned_data['position']

        with transaction.atomic():
            user = User.objects.create(username=username,email=email)
            userinfo = UserInfo.objects.create(user=user,phone=phone_number,position=position)
            userinfo.save()
            user.save()

        return super(TestView, self).form_valid(form)
```

but I got error like below.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/manager/test/

Django Version: 1.10.1
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'manager.apps.ManagerConfig',
 'mptt']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\apa\manager\templates\manager\alltoall.html, error at line 9
   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'   1 : <select multiple="multiple" data-field-name="groups">
   2 :     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   3 :     <option value="hyundai">Hyundai</option>
   4 : </select>
   5 : 
   6 : <form action="." method="post">
   7 :  {% csrf_token %}
   8 :  <table>
   9 :   {{ form }} 
   10 :     </table>
   11 :     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   12 : </form>

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  1050.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_value_in_context
  1028.     value = force_text(value)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in force_text
  76.                     s = six.text_type(s)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in <lambda>
  391.         klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in __str__
  123.         return self.as_table()

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in as_table
  271.             errors_on_separate_row=False)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _html_output
  226.                     'field': six.text_type(bf),

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in <lambda>
  391.         klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in __str__
  43.         return self.as_widget()

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in as_widget
  101.         return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render
  610.         options = self.render_options(value)

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render_options
  560.         for option_value, option_label in self.choices:

File "C:\Users\Jaemyun\django_real\apa\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __iter__
  1114.         queryset = self.queryset.all()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /manager/test/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override method `get_form_kwargs` from `FormView` class view in order to set inital data for your form.

```
class YouFormView(FormView):
    teplate_name = 'your template'
    form_class = YourForm


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        user = self.request.user
        form_kwargs = super(YouFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs.update({
            'initial': {
                'uperall': User.objects.filter(username=user.username)
            }
        })
        return form_kwargs
```

About mixing views: I recommend stick to class based view.

Comment: Thanks. I applied it to my code. but it caused "NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'". I am figuring out what caused this error. i happened during template rendering.

Comment: @JAEMYUNISGRANDPA paste error trace in your question.

Comment: Thanks for answer and idea to solve this. @levi I figured out my error. well first I changed form_kwargs.update part to form_kwargs['user'] = self.request.user. I just sent kwargs['user'] to __init__ of Form class. I wonder if it is right way but It works with Class based view now. I will look it up more about kwargs.update part.