# Django Form ChoiceField with Queryset

Tags: django, forms, model

I need to get the other users of the firm within the ModelForm to set the main user, I do not know how to get variables inside the form for this?

In the view the variable needed would be:

```
request.user.profile.firm
```

This is the form that needs to be created.

```
class FirmForm(forms.ModelForm):

    primary = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.filter(name=request.user.profile.firm))

    class Meta:
        model = Firm
```

The Profile Model:

```
class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firm = models.ForeignKey(
        Firm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

The Firm model

```
class Firm (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: can you be a little clear?? the question is not clear enough

Comment: I need to get all the other users of the Firm to set the Primary user in the ModelForm.  so I need to find a way to query the Users for all of them with the same Firm name.  is it possible?

Comment: post your models, and what is the error with this one

Comment: can I get request.user inside a Form?

Comment: please refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532316/django-forms-request-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
primary = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.filter(name=request.user.profile.firm.name))
```

use this in your model form

in views where you are accessing the Form

```
FirmForm(request=request)
```

Comment: it gives me an error inside the form with a request.

Comment: primary = forms.ModelChoiceField (queryset=User.objects.filter(name=request.user.profile.firm.name))
NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: form = FirmForm ( request.POST or None, instance = firm )

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work.  the best I could do.  Thanks.

```
def __init__ ( self,  *args, **kwargs ):
    super ( FirmForm, self ).__init__ ( *args, **kwargs )
    instance = getattr ( self, 'instance', None )
    firm = self.instance
    self.fields [ 'contact' ].queryset = Profile.objects.filter ( firm = firm )
```